# Search functionality in php cms

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, search

I'm using PHOZO for my Gallery & blog, I have setup many pages inside it, and now I realised there is no plugin/page-script available to accomplish internal search.
Are there plugin/scripts already? is it still under development? can I use it for production?

I have huge data here in this, cant move all manually into any other CMS,  please help me if some one used it already.

[Here is the URLs CMS page](http://www.phozo.org/)

Comment: Cum blog? Don`t post the url :))

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its already there in PHOZO, it has all the basic capabilities and you can use it for production, please check the [documentation here](http://www.phozo.org/documentation/).

Comment: I didnt find any helpful resource there, documentation is in-complete

Comment: try this, htp://www.yourdomain.com/installed-folder/search/keyword/